# What are the solvable subgroups of $S_n$?

Tags: group-theory

What are the solvable subgroup of $S_n$?

I know that when $n \geq 5$, both $S_n$ and $A_n$ are not solvable. But, how "large" can a solvable permutation group be when $n$ is given.

Many thanks~

Comment: The second question seems much more tractable than the first. Of course any finite solvable group is a subgroup of $S_n$ for some $n$...

Comment: Thanks for taking time to comment. I am sorry that I didn't make it clear. It is true that every finite group is a subroup of $S_n$ for some $n$. What I want to know is when $n$ is given, what the structures of solvable subgroups of $S_n$ are, and how "large" can they be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'll assume you mean: how large can the order of a solvable subgroup of the symmetric group on n points?

The largest nilpotent subgroup of the symmetric group of degree 2<sup>n</sup> is the Sylow 2-subgroup, an iterated wreath product of a very simple nilpotent group, the symmetric group on 2 points.  The largest nilpotent subgroup of a general symmetric group is just a direct product of these and sometimes the alternating group on three points.

Similarly, the largest solvable subgroup of the symmetric group of degree 4<sup>n</sup> is the iterated wreath product of a very compact solvable permutation group, the symmetric group on 4 points.  Using similar ideas, the associated bound for the order can be shown to hold for all symmetric groups:

> In Dixon (1967), it is shown that if G ≤ Sym(n) is a solvable permutation group of degree n, then |G| ≤ k<sup>(n−1)</sup>, where k≈2.88 is the cube root of 24.

Often one is interested in transitive or even primitive groups.  Then much smaller bounds are available, but the actual maximum order of a solvable transitive or primitive group of degree n depends as much on the arithmetic properties of n as on its size.  For instance, if n is prime and G is transitive, then |G| ≤ n(n−1) is a much smaller upper bound (attained by AGL(1,n)).  If G is solvable and primitive of degree n, then |G| ≤ n<sup>4</sup> (which even holds without the solvable hypothesis, by Prager–Saxl (1980)).  Pálfy (1982) gives even better bounds.

> Dixon, John D.
>   "The Fitting subgroup of a linear solvable group."
>   J. Austral. Math. Soc. 7 (1967) 417–424.
>   MR[230814](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=230814) DOI:[10.1017/S1446788700004353](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700004353)
>
> Pálfy, P. P.
>   "A polynomial bound for the orders of primitive solvable groups."
>   J. Algebra 77 (1982), no. 1, 127–137.
>   MR[665168](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=665168)
>   DOI:[10.1016/0021-8693(82)90281-2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(82)90281-2).

Comment: Note that Dixon's bound is attained (as Dixon himself remarked), whenever $n = 4^d$, using iterated wreath products of $S_4$ with itself.

Answer (score 7):

If $n = p$ is prime, then any transitive solvable subgroup of $S_p$ is contained 
in the group of affine transformations $x \mapsto ax + b$ (here $a \in \mathbb F_p^{\times}$ and $b \in \mathbb F_p$), thought of as a group of transformations from $\mathbb F_p$ (a set of order $p$) to itself.  (This result goes back to Galois himself, and was one of the motivations for his invention of finite fields.)

Comment: Could you kindly tell me where can i get account of the result of galois regarding prime degree polynomials...@MattE

Comment: Dear Sayak, Have you looked in E. Artin's book on Galois theory?  I'm told that it is in there, although I haven't studied that book myself.   I learnt about it from [Hans Wussing's book](http://http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Genesis_of_the_Abstract_Group_Concep.html?id=RbMrAAAAYAAJ) on the history of group theory. Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Here's a lower bound. For a prime $p$ and an integer $n$ let $\nu_p(n)$ denote the greatest power of $p$ dividing $n$. Recall that
$$\nu_p(n!) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor \approx \frac{n}{p-1}.$$

It follows that the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_n$ (which, being a $p$-group, is automatically solvable) has order about $p^{ \frac{n}{p-1} }$. For fixed $n$ this is maximized when $p = 2$, giving a solvable subgroup of $S_n$ of order about $2^n$.