# Order of subgroup of symmetric group within an interval

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

Consider symmetric group $S_n$. I want to find a subgroup of $S_n$ whose order is around a number $m$. For example I want to find a subgroup whose order is within 10000 to 12000 of $S_{17}$.
What is the procedure? Please help

Answer (score 0):

The group $S_{17}$ has order
$$
2^{15}\cdot 3^6\cdot 5^3\cdot 7^2\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 17.
$$
Hence the largest nilpotent subgroup has order $2^{15}$. It is a Sylow $2$-subgroup. The subgroups of it have orders $2^k$ with $k\le 15$, which are not between $10000$ and $12000$. What about a direct product of Sylow subgroups?

Concerning large solvable subgroups, see

[What are the solvable subgroups of $S_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36237/what-are-the-solvable-subgroups-of-s-n)